Converting Locator to FrameLocator - 'ContentFrame' not available
I am locating a frame object by a attribute data-test-id, check its uri and then want to access its DOM. So I first use ILocator and then want to return IFrameLocator for accessing the iframe.
The playwright doc says I can use Locator.ContentFrame to directly convert my Locator to an FrameLocator
https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-framelocator
Unfortuanally it seems not to be available.
Both return variants does not provide this property.
            var frameElement = page.Locator($"{pageInformation.FrameIdentifier}");

            var debugSrc = await frameElement.GetAttributeAsync("src");
            await Assertions.Expect(frameElement).ToHaveAttributeAsync("src", regex);

            return frameElement.ContentFrame;
            return page.Frames[0].ContentFrame

I checked whether I am too old but I am running at version 1.44.1. ContentFrame was added in 1.43
npx @playwright/test --version
Version 1.44.1

I also tried frameElement.FrameLocator(string.Empty) as to reference itself, but as expected, did not work ;)
Next I found out that Locator.FaitForSelectorAsync provides kind of it: ContentFrameAsync(). But it does not return a IFrameLocator, it returns a IFrame. As it seems, i can not switch from it to a locator.
            var frameElement = await page.WaitForSelectorAsync($"{pageInformation.FrameIdentifier}");

            var frameSource = await frameElement.GetAttributeAsync("src");

            Throw<Exception>.If(
                () => !regex.Match(frameSource).Success,
                "Found iFrame does not contain expected url.");

            return frameElement.ContentFrameAsync();


I just went with an additional var framelocator = page.FrameLocator($"{pageInformation.FrameIdentifier}"); for now buts its not nice because in a way I am stating the same thing 2 times und the doc says it should be possible with ContentFrame.
